# Brute force function for decrypting string in C (Caesar cipher )

Tags: c, for-loop, encryption

I found this problem interesting, as it is given that you need to use the alphabet as an array in C. Task is to brute force every possible K value, in basic Caesar's cipher manner.

However, code I come up with compile non-true values after `K = 1`. For example, a letter `C` is turned to `Z` instead of `A` etc. Can anyone spot what I did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void bruteforce (char*);  

int main() {
    char cyphertext[] = "kyvtrmrcipnzccrkkrtbwifdkyvefikynvjkrkeffe";
    bruteforce(cyphertext);

    return 0;
}

void bruteforce (char *cyphertext) {
    char alphabet[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    long int size = strlen(cyphertext);

    for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++){
        for (long int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
                if (alphabet[j] == cyphertext[i]){
                    cyphertext[i] = alphabet[j - k];
                    if (k > j){
                        cyphertext[i] = alphabet[26 + j - k];
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
        printf("%s\n ", cyphertext);
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 nested loops?? For what? Write a function `decrypt`. Then run it with 26 possible keys.

Comment: Your problem is that every pass changes the ciphertext: First you shift by 0; nothing happens. Then you shift by 1. Next you shift the already shifted text by 2, for an effective shift of 3. Either make the decrypted text a separate array or shift 26 times by just 1.

Comment: Note that modern writing usually uses "cipher" rather than "cypher". And Caesar is written with the 'a' before the 'e' (originally "CAIVS IVLIVS CAESAR" in Latin script).

Answer (score 1):

For Caesar Cypher shifting, you don't need to use the alphabet string. You can just shift the character in ASCII code. ASCII codes of 'a' - 'z' are 97 - 122. Thus if decode with + 1. If the characters are a - z, you can just add one to each character. If after adding the shift value to the character value and the character value become larger than 122 then take the character value and subtract it to 122 then add 96 to that.

For shifting negative, if character value become smaller than 97. Take 97 subtract to character's value. Then subtract 123 to the previous equation value. Nonetheless, I built the code so that negative shift will be convert to positive shift. If the shift is negative we take 26 and add to that. Example is, shifting -1 will make a become z. So that is similar to shifting 26 + -1 = 25.

Shift value can be larger than +25 or smaller than -25. Nonetheless, if it is, it will be modulus to 26.

If you want to bruteforce all the possible combinations for a string. Just use the function below and run it in a loop from 1 to 25. But your function modify the original string. Thus, when doing bruteforce, you would have to copy the string of your function to a temporary string and let the function work on that. The examples are below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void bruteforce (char *cyphertext, int shiftBy);

int main() {
    char cyphertext[] = "kyvtrmrcipnzccrkkrtbwifdkyvefikynvjkrkeffe";
    char cyphertext2[] = "yvccf wifd bvmze";
    bruteforce(cyphertext, -17);
    puts("");
    bruteforce(cyphertext2, 9);       

    /* Bruteforce example */
    puts("");
    puts("Bruteforce section:");
    // +9
    char cyphertext3[] = "kyzjkvokzjkfsvtirtb nyrk tre kyzj sv zj zk yvccf nficu";
    char temp[50];

    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
       printf("Trying to crack by shifting %d \n", i );
       strcpy(temp, cyphertext3);
       bruteforce(temp, i);
       puts("");
    }
    /* End Bruteforce example */

    return 0;
}
// If there is no shift i.e 0, 26, 52, -26
// It won't print
void bruteforce (char *cyphertext, int shiftBy){
    size_t size = strlen(cyphertext);

    if ( shiftBy > 25){
        shiftBy = shiftBy % 26;
    } else if ( shiftBy < 0 ) {
        shiftBy = 26 + (shiftBy % 26);
        // If shiftBy is 26 
        // there is no need to shift.
        if ( shiftBy == 26 ) return;
    }

    // If there is no shift return.
    if ( shiftBy == 0 ) return;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
          // 97 - 122 is a - z
          // if char is a - z
          if ( cyphertext[i] > 96 && cyphertext[i] < 123 ){
              // add shift by
              cyphertext[i] += shiftBy;
              // if char > z
              // then take char - z then add to the ascii code that just before 'a'.
              // Since shiftBy is converted fomr negative to positive., 
              // There will not be a negative shiftBy.
              if ( (unsigned char)cyphertext[i] > 122 )
                  cyphertext[i] = ((unsigned char) cyphertext[i]) - 122 + 96;
          }

          // If want to do A - Z 
          // ASCII code are 65 - 90.
    }
    printf("%s\n", cyphertext);
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of magics here. I'd use `'a'` instead of `96`. Furthermore, I would first bring the characters down to an integer value between in the range [0, 26) and then perform modular addition (or, for decryption, subtraction). Changing input strings is dangerous as well, why not copy it in the function and then return the plaintext or ciphertext instead of `void`?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica - 'a' is not 96. If I was to write this for myself I would return a heap string, but since the OP wanted it like that, I think you would be better off telling the OP that. For bringing down the character to 0 - 26 then modulus. I don't think that efficient as you would have to bring the character back to it original value. If were to modulus any value, I would modulus the shiftBy value or if its value is neg, I convert it to its appropriate positive value, so I that I save one evaluation per character.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica - Thank you for your comment. I forgot that I could modulus the shifBy value. I also forgot that I could convert the shiftBy value to its positive counterpart. Thank you for reminding me. I fixed the code to make it more robust and more efficient. Also, I fixed the typo before 'a' - 'z'.